# What is the insulation in this hot water jacket?

Tags: insulation

Taking apart an old water heater and found this jacket - ripped to shreds, probably by the cat. Is it likely this contains asbestos or is it fibreglass?

[image]

[Here is a video](https://youtu.be/ZMfJIHeL8Jw)

Thanks.

Comment: Fiberglass melts when you hit it with a blowtorch. Asbestos will laugh at you.

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely fiberglass since that's what's been used in water heaters for many years.  You didn't specify how old it is and if it's "ancient" there does exist that possibility.  If in doubt, get it tested and properly disposed of by a licensed abatement contractor.

I suspect, however, that old is 10-15 years which is "forever" in water heater years and in that case there will be no asbestos.

Comment: It’s fiberglass, water heaters were not routinely wrapped until after asbestos was outlawed in the U.S. asbestos looks nothing like fiberglass and that looks like faded Owens Corning pink.